# iptables error trying to set up docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm new to EOS and trying to follow the guide: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart.

On step 2, I get an error for iptables.

```
$ docker network create eosdev
Error response from daemon: Failed to program FILTER chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -I FORWARD -o br-17b2333c469e -j DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h'
```

Unsure how to resolve this. OS is Linux Mint 19 Tara x64.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a eosio specific problem, so it may turn out to be more helpful to ask the docker community as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by

```
~/scripts $ sudo service docker stop
[sudo] password for user:


~/scripts $ sudo service docker start
~/scripts $ ./docker_init.sh
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/eosio" is already in use by container "a449dc043cd46b79775c239fc2c356637c888c704a4cf11299ae0d605d5a34b1". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

See 'docker run --help'.

```
~/scripts $ docker rm eosio
eosio
```

And then rebuild the container using:

```
  docker run --name eosio \
   --publish 7777:7777 \
  --publish 127.0.0.1:5555:5555 \
  --volume CONTRACTS_DIR:CONTRACTS_DIR \
  --detach \
  eosio/eos:v1.4.2 \
  /bin/bash -c \
  "keosd --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:5555 & exec nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:7777 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false --filter-on='*'"
```

Hope that helps!